# Proper use of og meta tags on website

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I have a website that has deeplinking enabled. When I try to add the image link to facebook, it comes up with one of three images to choose from for the share.

I have the proper meta tags added for opengraph. However, because I want the ability to share any one of the 40 images on the site, is it ok to add an

```
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
```

tag for every image, or is there a wiser to to solve this issue?

Additionally, should I/should I not add individual **description** tags, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple `og:image`s, but the share dialog will only show three of them to the user to chose from.

And if you have individual pieces of content those of course should have an individual descriptions as well (where appropriate).

More information on general Open Graph tags can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories#objecttypes-properties and here: http://ogp.me/